# Cell probe model

Tags: algorithm

From Algorithms 4th Edition

**Q. What is the cell-probe model?**  
A model of computation where we only count accesses to a random-access memory
large enough to hold the input and consider all other operations to be free.

I want to understand this statement. Please help me understand this with examples.

Answer (score 2):

Problem: determine whether the number 0 appears in the input, which must be a sorted list L. The cell-probe complexity is *exactly* ceil(log2(len(L) + 1)) by binary search because that's how many elements of L we have to look at. We don't need big-O to state this result because the overhead of dispatching the probes is not counted.

Problem: determine whether the input is a satisfiable Boolean formula (SAT). Even though this problem is NP-complete and thus not known to have a polynomial-time algorithm, we do know that the cell-probe complexity is at most n, because one algorithm is to read the entire input and do an exponential-time computation that doesn't make any probes.

Since the cell-probe model allows unrealistic amounts of computation, it is almost always used as the setting for an impossibility result, that is, even if we had all the time and space in the world, no algorithm could access less than this much of the input.